# LINQ VB.NET Return multiple columns

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a LINQ statement that will return all the fields in a row.  How can I modify this statement to return just two fields, "Address 1" and "Address 2"?  (row is a DataRow)

```
Dim fields As String() = row.ItemArray.Select(Function(field) field.ToString()).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
Dim fields As String() = (From obj In {row.Item("a1"), row.Item("a2")} Select CStr(obj)).ToArray()
```

Comment: Works like a champ, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DataGridViewRows?  I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but I think you're looking for [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx).

Ex.:

```
Dim fields = New With {.Column1 = row.Cells.Item("Column1Name"), _
                       .Column2 = row.Cells.Item("Column2Name")}
```